Unsure how to get my Android Studio gradle to use the same syntax found in all the online tutorials
I am writing an Android app on my Mac Book Pro (M3 running Sonoma) with a recently downloaded Android Studio. When I start a new Java project, the options for gradle are:

Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.kts) [Recommended]
Groovy DSL (build.gradle)

The first has the syntax: implementation(libs.appcompat)
The second has the syntax: implementation libs.appcompat
However, most of the recent online tutorials use the syntax: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.1.0'
A bit of digging reveals that the syntax I see in the tutorials is the newest one and I should switch to it. But I just downloaded a new Android Studio before posting this note and it didn't change things. Is there some obvious setting I'm just missing?
I have also consulted Google's Gemini AI, which suggested I change the project-level gradle file, which it specifically states should be the build.gradle and not the build.gradle.kts file but, when I open my project, I only see two gradle files -- and they're both named build.gradle.kts.


The first has the syntax: implementation(libs.appcompat)
The second has the syntax: implementation libs.appcompat

This is from Gradle version catalogs, which is available to both Kotlin (.gradle.kts) and Groovy (.gradle) files.

However, most of the recent online tutorials use the syntax: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.1.0'

This eschews the use of version catalogs.

A bit of digging reveals that the syntax I see in the tutorials is the newest one and I should switch to it.

That is incorrect. Gradle version catalogs is newer and is Google's current direction with respect to the new-project wizard. However, Android Studio can open and work with projects that do not use version catalogs.

Is there some obvious setting I'm just missing?

IIRC, no. It would have been a good idea had they provided options for both using and skipping version catalogs in the new-project wizard, but IIRC they elected to not do that.

The syntax with the brackets also works in Groovy, not only Kotlin script.
